# Cordova / Phonegap not generating Assets / WWW folder

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have tried using Cordova 2.4 & 2.7 to no avail. The project seems to build fine when using the `create` method in console, except it does not create the whole program structure. The `www` folder is missing (or assets?).

[image]

When I open the project in Eclipse, I can see the assets folder on the left sidebar pane, but there is no children (it is empty).

The default app builds and runs fine (it just says "Hello World, App").

[image]

I should note that I tried this in `cygwin` also, and it came up with an error.

```
An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

[image]

I am using Windows 7 x64 with Eclipse 4.2.2, Cordova 2.7 (also tried 2.4). I have the ADT plugin installed on Eclipse, and here is a screenshot of my SDK manager.

[image]

I have the entries in my PATH variable set that I followed in the [Getting Started](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) tutorial.

If anyone has some input or ideas in how to resolve this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hey If  you are creating a project then you have to create a assets/www folder etc,You have to make changes in other files too.

Follow the link below you have all the information you need

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

Be sure to change the cordova version etc,as per your requirement.